# Matlab Trust-region-reflective algorithm warning

Tags: optimization, finance, matlab, quadratic-programming

I am very new to matlab and trying to solve portfolio optimization problem (minimizing the variance) using quadprog:

```
minW = quadprog(t_covar, v0, [], [], e, ub, lb, [], []);
```

where t_covar is the covariance matrix, v0 is a zero vector, e is the identity vector, ub = 1 and lb is a zero vector. It seems to work fine but I get this warning:

Warning: Trust-region-reflective algorithm does not solve this type of problem, using
active-set algorithm. You could also try the interior-point-convex algorithm: set the
Algorithm option to interior-point-convex and rerun.

Am I doing something wrong ? Should I worry about this warning ?

Hope I was clear thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing something wrong.  The [most recent version of `quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/quadprog.html) has this argument set:

```
quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0,options)
```

If you're using the most recent version of Matlab, then your function call has $e$, $ub$, and $lb$ being stuffed into the $Aeq$, $beq$, and $lb$ parameters, respectively.  I don't think that's what you want, as (for example) $beq$ is supposed to be the right-hand side of an equality constraint, while $ub$ is your upper bound.

You're getting the warning message because you didn't specify a particular algorithm for the `quadprog` function to use, and so `quadprog` is trying the default algorithm, which is the trust-region-reflective algorithm.  That algorithm apparently doesn't work on your problem.  This is probably because of the parameter passing issue I mentioned above, as the trust-region-reflective algorithm works when the problem has "only bounds, or only linear equality constraints (but not both)."  (For more information, see "[Choosing a solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-18.html)" in the Matlab documentation.)

Since the trust-region-reflective algorithm doesn't work, `quadprog` is trying the next algorithm in line, which is apparently the active-set algorithm.  Then it's telling you that you might get better results with the interior-point-convex algorithm.

> So, which algorithm should you use?

[Matlab's general recommendations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-18.html#bsbwx47) for the algorithm for the `quadprog` function are

- If you have a convex problem, or if you don't know whether your
  problem is convex, use interior-point-convex.
- If you have only bounds, or only linear equalities, use
  trust-region-reflective.
- If you have a nonconvex problem that does not satisfy the
  restrictions of trust-region-reflective, use active-set.

> Since you're passing `quadprog` a covariance matrix (which must be positive semidefinite) your problem is convex.  **So it sounds like the interior-point-convex method is the way to go.**

For more information, see "[Using Quadratic Programming on Portfolio Optimization Problems](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/optim/portfoptimdemo.html)" in the Matlab documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. I think I misused the ub and lb terms since I was using this (http://goo.gl/Qtcnh) book's algorithm as an help and misinterpreted some values as being ub and lb (and therefore named that as like that). minW = quadprog(t_covar, v0, [], [], e, 1, v0, [], []) is the real call where e is a vector of ones and v0 is a vector of zeros. I still get the warning and the same result but I guess it should be alright now.

Comment: @Cemre: You're welcome.  As I said, I would use the interior-point algorithm rather than the trust-region-reflective algorithm, though.